# Class has no instance method '[]' Flutter

Tags: api, flutter

I am new to Flutter. I'm trying to get data from API to be used in FutureBuilder widget. I generated the API model and supply the data gotten from the response.body to the model

```
class ArticleList {
  final List<Articles> articles;

  ArticleList({this.articles});

  factory ArticleList.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson){
    List<Articles> articles = <Articles>[];
     articles = parsedJson.map((i)=> Articles.fromJson(i)).toList();
   
    return ArticleList(articles: articles);
  }
 
}

 
class Articles {
  Source source;
  String author;
  String title;
  String description;
  String url;
  String urlToImage;
  String publishedAt;
  String content;

  Articles(
      {this.source,
      this.author,
      this.title,
      this.description,
      this.url,
      this.urlToImage,
      this.publishedAt,
      this.content});
        
  Articles.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    source =
        json['source'] != null ? new Source.fromJson(json['source']) : null;
    author = json['author'];
    title = json['title'];
    description = json['description'];
    url = json['url'];
    urlToImage = json['urlToImage'];
    publishedAt = json['publishedAt'];
    content = json['content'];
  }
    
}


class Network {

  Future getNews() async{
    Response response =await get(Uri.parse("https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=Apple&from=2021-05-12&sortBy=popularity&apiKey="));
    if(response.statusCode == 200){ 
      var a = json.decode(response.body)['articles']; 
      return ArticleList.fromJson(a);
    }else{
      
      throw Exception("Failed");
    }
  }
```

I'm getting error
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState#3a80a):
Class 'ArticleList' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: Instance of 'ArticleList'
Tried calling:

Answer (score 0):

Because your `ArticleList` is not an array, is his attribute `articles`.

Comment: I thought I made it a list with  List<Articles> articles = <Articles>[];
     articles = parsedJson.map((i)=> Articles.fromJson(i)).toList();